# User have to select what MyApp can access when Login | Google OAuth 2

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to create offline access for my app by using google OAuth 2. When I redirect to AuthUrl, everything is great except user have to select roles before authorize.[image]

And here is my initial code:

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2({
    clientId: googleapi.client_id,
    redirectUri: googleapi.redirect_uri,
    clientSecret: googleapi.client_secret,
  })
return res.status(403).json({
      message: 'A token is required for authentication',
      authUrl: oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: googleapi.scopes,
        state: prevUrl,
        include_granted_scopes: false,
        prompt: 'consent',
      }),
    })
```